# Jruby JavaMail undefined method getUID

Tags: jruby, jakarta-mail

I am trying to use POP3 JavaMail package to fetch email messages. Based on the JavaMail documentation both IMAPFolder and POP3Folder have getUID() methods. However the code works fine with IMAP but not with POP3. With POP3 I get the following error: ``` undefined method ``getUID' for #<Java::ComSunMailPop3::POP3Message:0x66d7cba7> ```.
Below is the code:
`server_messages = mbox.selectedfolder.getMessages()
    msgs_to_be_fetched = Array.new
    fetchprofile = javax.mail.FetchProfile.new()
    fetchprofile.add(javax.mail.UIDFolder::FetchProfileItem::UID)
    fetchprofile.add(javax.mail.FetchProfile::Item::FLAGS)
    mbox.selectedfolder.fetch(server_messages, fetchprofile)
    server_messages.each { |server_msg|
        next if server_msg.getFlags().contains(javax.mail.Flags::Flag::DELETED)
        uid = server_msg.getUID()
        msgs_to_be_fetched << server_msg unless msg_exists(uid)
} unless server_messages.nil?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue. With IMAP I can just call message.getUID() but with POP3 I have to use the folder. Code below:
`def getMessageUID(serverType,folder,msg)
    return (serverType == 'imap'? msg.getUID() : folder.getUID(msg))
    end`